# How to collect all the reviews on the website using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, geckodriver

I am using the following code to collect all the reviews on a page, but it collects only the first one. However, the xpath used in the code highlights 10 elements when elements are inspected on the website.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g262047-d568915-Reviews-Spiaggia_dei_Conigli-Lampedusa_Islands_of_Sicily_Sicily.html"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
time.sleep(5)

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

# accepts the cookie
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler'))).click()

# clicks to reach the review page
inputElement = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[@href="#REVIEWS"]/div/span').click()
time.sleep(5)

# attempt 1: does not catch all 10 reviews
#reivew_list = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@style="line-break: normal; cursor: auto;"]/div/span')


# attempt 2: does not catch all 10 reviews
review_list = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-automation="reviewCard"]//div[5]/div[1]/div/span')


for review in review_list:
    rev = review.text

    print(rev)
```

Please help me understand how to collect all the reviews on the webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently using `driver.find_element()` which returns exactly 1 matching element (the first found within DOM tree).

Just change it to `driver.find_elements()` which returns all matching elements.

An overview for the selenium python library:
[1]: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: Thank you so much @Knight . I was wondering what I kept doing wrong and you spotted it right. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome, glad i could help. If your problem got solved you can accept this answer, so everyone sees the question got answered.